# printing speed, CUPS, Epson TM-T88IV, PI 3

Tags: pi-3, printing, cups

I need to setup a RasPi for some hardware things in a p.o.s. environment, like scanners, scale and printers (3 printers).
So I took a brand new RasPi, did a complete new installation with apache2, cups and the epsonsimplecups driver, found [here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGOcgz6z81I) and [here on Github](https://github.com/plinth666/epsonsimplecups) and connected a thermo printer Epson TM-T88IV.
Everything went without any errors, including setup CUPS for external access.
Now I can print local files and over network, so good so far.

But it prints terribly slow, which doesn't mean minutes, but 10 to 12 seconds for a small receipt (.pdf) as well as a 20 lines plain text file (.txt).

May it lacking on the RasPi side, or should I test another printer like TM-T88V instead of TM-T88IV ?

Any experiences anybody ? Thanks for sharing.

Comment: PS.: I also installed a DYMO LabelWriter 450, and it works fast as expected, including a number of copies.

Comment: Have you tried setting your printer as a RAW printer?

Comment: PS2.: I gave python a try, using python-cups and a python script with printing commands. It's working, but with same results, prints slow.

Comment: @Dr.Rabbit Yes I did, it's printing fast, but it doesn't print my .pdf, which is generated on the server. Instead I got 3 meters garbage paper :-)

Comment: Hmm, maybe try something like [python-escpos](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in conjuntion with [pdf-miner](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six)

Comment: @Dr.Rabbit great answer. Not directly answered my question, but you pushed me to walk on completely new tracks. I got python-escpos running, it turns out that the PDF creation is completely senseless, since escpos is also able to handle images, which are printed in good quality, which was the reason for using PDF before. And escpos is muuuuch faster because PDF must not be created, it must not be downloaded, and it must not be processed by the printer driver. At the end... the lacking printer driver mentioned in the question is completely obsolete, since  escpos doesn'n need it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the package from plinth666 but the raster wasn't quite proper and the print timing waas quiet long.

I used then a bunch of free code from Epson, a PPD file from another printer and modify them to produce this new package: https://github.com/groolot/epson-tm-t88v-driver

Better rasterization, cash drawer and buzzer, all is operational.

Hope that could help someone like I was: in pain.